# Evaluating $\int 4 e^x - x^3 + 6x - 8 \ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem asks to integrate the following: $$\int 4 e^x - x^3 + 6x - 8 \ dx$$ 
So far I got
$$4e^x-(x^4/4)+(6x^2/2)+8x+c$$
Is this correct?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: this is what I got 4e^x-(x^4/4)+(6x^2/2)+8x+c? Is this the answer?

Comment: The $x^2$ term has the wrong coefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

Use the additivity of the integral: Given functions $\{ f_i \}_{i=1}^n $, we have

$$ \int \sum f_i = \sum \int f_i $$

In your case, $f_1 = 4e^x, f_2 = -x^3, f_3 = 6x, f_4 = -8$. These are fairly easy to integrate, but here are some formulae:

$$ \int e^x = e^x + K $$

$$ \int x^n = \frac{ x^{n+1} }{n+1} + K , \; \;\;\; (n \neq1)$$

Obviously, if $K$ is a constant,

$$ \int K f = K \int f $$

$$ \text{Answer:}  \;\;\;\; 4e^x - \frac{ x^4}{4} + 3x^2 - 8x + K $$

Comment: is the answer: 4e^x-(x^4/4)+(6x^2/2)+8x+c?

Comment: my book uses c not k

Comment: I have added the solution: Compare your answer. Yours is almost correct except at the end $+8x$ should be $-8x$

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!!! Also would the K be the same as a C in your answer?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. $K = C $ they are just constants.